# Remove nodes which are single or have 2nd degree visjs

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

I've a network graph [image: Lots of nodes]

Now I've some connected nodes and as you can see most of the nodes only have one connected node that is their degree is 1. Now I'd like to remove such nodes to clear the clutter. Unable to find how to since last 2 days. No such helper functions available in visjs documentation. Would appreciate help.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the algorithm suggested by the 1st answer -by macramole- (before updates) would actually hide the non-connected nodes (degree 0), instead of the ones with degree 1. 
I would probably just iterate over all the edges in the network while keeping 'degree' counters for each node that is an endpoint in the edge you are visiting (you can obtain these nodes by grabbing the edge.from and edge.to values, as shown above). You would increment the degree counter for a node, whenever the node is 'hit' in this search through the edges. 
Eventually you'll end up with the degree value for each node in the network, at which point you can decide which ones to hide. 
Updating this answer now to include my suggested code (note: nodes and edges are vis DataSet instances):

Example code:

```
var nodeToDegrees = {}; // keeps a map of node ids to degrees
var nodeFrom, nodeTo;
for (edge in edges) {
    nodeFrom = edge.from;
    nodeTo = edge.to;
    nodeToDegrees[nodeFrom] = nodeToDegrees[nodeFrom] ? nodeToDegrees[nodeFrom] + 1 : 0;
    nodeToDegrees[nodeTo] = nodeToDegrees[nodeTo] ? nodeToDegrees[nodeTo] + 1 : 0;
}
for (node in nodes) {
    if (nodeToDegrees[node.id] = 1) nodes.update([{node.id, hidden: true}]);
}
```

Comment: Yes , you are right, the algorithm above can be use as a starting point, but OP should add counters and hide where the counter is 1

Comment: thanks for the comment. I have now updated my answer too, to provide code which illustrates the difference ( no two-level loop, which is more expensive)

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
var DEGREES_HIDDEN = 1;

for ( var node of nodes ) {
    node.cantLinks = 0;

    for ( var link of links ) {
        if ( link.from == node.id || link.to == node.id ) {
            node.cantLinks++;
        }
    }
}
for ( var node of nodes ) {
   if ( node.cantLinks <= DEGREES_HIDDEN ) {
       node.hidden = true;
   }  
}
```

Nodes and links are arrays not vis.DataSet, I create the latter after doing that.

Doesn't look very nice perfomance wise but it does get the job done. Hope you find it useful.